# How can I add a "plus sign/icon" to my portfolio shots???

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a "plus sign" (its a .png file) to my portfolio section. My goal is to make this "plus sign" visible only when customers are hovering with mouse pointer over my projects but in the same time I want to keep the background-color property which I already set up.

However, my plus sign doesn't show up!? How can I do that???

On this website you can see the similar effect: http://bjorsberg.se/

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8HX7/

This is a part of my CSS (from JSFiddle) that needs to be fixed:

```
.plus{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -49px 0 0 -56px;
    background: url(img/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Here is example of a plus sign I want to add: http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Very-Basic-Plus-icon.png

Comment: Looks good. The image obviously doesn’t show up in the Fiddle since it’s using a relative path … EDIT Ah, the style obviously has to be applied to the *hover* style. Just replace the `background-color` in `.projectshot a .over:hover{` by the appropriate `background`. You don’t need the `div.plus` at all.

Comment: I added this image just for the people here so they can help me. I am using similar one from img/plus.png folder but it's not working???

Comment: :hover is not using ".plus", it is using another declaration. Also, the image you want to use is may times larger than your images.

Comment: I realize both things but culdn't make it work :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really broken down example.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/UVvWm/

CSS

```
.block {
    position: relative; /* so the .plus knows what to be relative to */
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: red;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}


.block:hover .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.block .plus {
    display: none;
}

.block:hover .plus {
    display: block;
}



/* to position the .plus */
.plus {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#"class="block">

    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <img class="plus" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />

</a>
```

You could use an :after psuedo element for the overlay - but I wanted to keep it simple.  Keep in mind that CSS declarations read from right to left .... "any .plus - do this, when .block:hover" etc ----

Comment: Ok. I'll try to make it following your instructions above. Hope I can make it. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it!!! Those .block links should be in a unordered list probably, I just made the link for the example.

Answer (score 1):

The style obviously has to be applied *on hover*.

Just replace the `background-color` in `.projectshot a .over:hover{` by the appropriate `background`. You don’t need the `div.plus` at all, and neither do you need `div.inner` (you can remove those from the HTML!):

```
.projectshot a .over:hover{
    position: absolute;
    background: url(img/plus.png) center center no-repeat rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here’s the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8HX7/8/

Comment: Thanks. This is a step forward. Do I have to resize the plus sign or I can do it with CSS???

Comment: @C.Felipe I’d resize it in an image manipulation program, that’s easier and seems entirely appropriate here.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do it. I thought it could be done with CSS just like I did it with all other images here (their original size is 800x600 but they show up as 200x150.

Comment: You should put the plus in a div... - size the div how you want - set the .plus ing {display:block; width:100%; height: auto;}  make the image 130% the size you want it so that it'll be crisp on retina?